# Main thread wait for other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

After seaching a lot and not finding a concrete answer

If I have two threads started:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

After starting the threads I need the main thread to wait for these two thread to finish before printing the final result

How can I make the main thread wait for both t1 and t2?

A plain `wait()` would be enough?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add

```
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

in your thread which should wait till `t1` and `t2` will finish their tasks (in your case call it from your main thread).

Answer (score 9):

The answer depends...

## You could

Use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which is probably the simplest solution.

This way you would simply `wait` on the latch until it has been signaled the prescribed number of times (by each `Thread` terminating).  This scales quite nicely as you increase the number of threads...

## You could

Use `join`, but it would become tedious as you add more threads

## You could

Add each `Thread` to a `List`, loop through the list, removing those threads that are no longer alive and keep looping until the `List` is empty, but that's a rather heavy handed approach.

## You could

Combine the above solution with some kind of monitor lock which the `loop` would `wait` on and each `Thread` would `notify` when they complete, but it's not much cleaner and you could still end up waiting for non-existent threads...

## You could

Use an `ExecutorService` and either use it's `invokeAll` and/or `shutdown` methods.  See [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) for more details.  This also scales quite nicely and even has the added benefit of allowing you to use a `Thread` pool to better manage the system resourcs

Comment: @MyNameIsRui Hope some of it helps ;)

Comment: Re "You could use join, but it would become tedious as you add more threads".  The tedium becomes O(1) if you add each new thread to a List, and then iterate over the list when it's time to .join() all of them.  I haven't learned Java8 yet, but I'm pretty sure it would be just one fairly simple looking line of code.

Comment: @james But a CountDownLatch or ExecutorService would be way simpler regardless

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Thread#join method.

Also, you might find using an ExecutorService (and friends) helpful.  Its essentially thread pool/management and provides a lot of conveniences and IMO a cleaner API than threads.  Barrier to entry is low...

Answer (score 1):

You want `Thread#join()`. `wait()` is for signalling, `join()` is to wait for the thread to finish.